# Getting same frame each time using FFmpegFrameGrabber.grabImage() in Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, javacv

Trying to extract each frame from a video file using javaCV, FFFmpegFramGrabber and save as jpg, end up getting the same frame each time.

```
      FFmpegFrameGrabber grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(cVideoFilePath+ "/" + "VID_20170211_132657.mp4");
    try {
        AndroidFrameConverter convertToBitmap = new AndroidFrameConverter();
        grabber.start();

        for (int i= 0; i< grabber.getFrameRate();i++){

             frame1 = grabber.grabImage();
            Bitmap bitmap = convertToBitmap.convert(frame1);
            String date = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
            File picfile = new File(file_name);
            if (!picfile.exists()) {
                try {
                    picfile.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            try {

                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(picfile);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {

            } finally {

            }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop looks wrong. Here is how this loop is expected to be:

```
int frame_count = grabber.getLengthInFrames();
for (int i=0; i<frame_count; i+=grabber.getFrameRate())
```

Comment: still getting the same frame each time, though when deluging the of value i increments as it should be but the output image is same each time

Comment: It is not clear how you generate `file_name`. Probably you do not create a new file for each frame.

Comment: Thanks Alex now getting all the frames as needed. but the problem is with latency, getting only 2 frames per second.

Comment: If this is not a live stream, your procedure may be responsible. Try to write the grabbed frames "as black boxes" to disk to estimate (by extraction) the time it takes to convert them to bitmap and then to jpeg.